# Results from extractAIC() from a mixed model lmer() are confusing

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, aic, degrees-of-freedom

I have some legacy code in larger block of looped code that compares models.
It essentially boils down to this similar example:

```
library(lme4)
data("iris")
test1 <- lmer(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width + (1|Species), data = iris, REML = FALSE)
extractAIC(test1)
```

Which in this case gives the result:

```
> extractAIC(test1)
[1]  4.00000 89.74898
```

I am to understand from the return values for the function that the first value is `edf, the ‘equivalent degrees of freedom’ for the fitted model`, however I am also to understand that degrees of freedom are not valid in mixed models except under some special circumstances? It's not clear what it does in an `lmer()` class.

My question then is, when using `lmer()`, is this 'K' specifically, the number of parameters? For my data I am getting numbers in the 30's to 40's. Also, I am quite confused as to how 'number of parameters' is explained, and how important it is.

I have found some very heavy explanations I think, but I need some more layman terms to explain how it is somehow derived from the random and fixed effects, and their variance and/or covariance (across those groups?)?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! I took the liberty of adding the [tag:aic] tag to your question. [AIC and mixed models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model%2baic) are not quite trivial... I hope you get a helpful answer!

Comment: The edf is calculated by `lme4:::npar.merMod`. If you study the source code, you see that it is the sum of the number of fixed-effect parameters (`test1@beta`), the number of covariance parameters (`test1@theta`, i.e., one per random effect) + 1 if there is a scaling parameter (which is always the case for `lmer` models according to `help("lmList", "lme4")`).

Comment: Thank you, that makes some sense. Though, I am also wondering how is it useful when comparing AIC values for models that may have different numbers of parameters?

Comment: The AIC is calculated as `-2 * L + k * edf` where L is the log-likelihood and k = 2 per default. As you see, the estimated degrees of freedom are used for a penalty term for the number of paramaters in a model. This term counters the effect that more complex models can always fit the data better than simpler models (at least if the models are nested). So, the whole point of AIC is that it allows comparing models with different number of parameters. Otherwise, you could just compare likelihoods directly.

Comment: Ahhh. Now I get it. Thanks again. I would uptick that, but I don't have that ability yet, so please accept this personalised response.

Comment: I have transferred my comments to an answer since I now know that they provide the information you were after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edf are calculated by `lme4:::npar.merMod`. If you study the source code, you see that it is the sum of the number of fixed-effect parameters (`test1@beta`), the number of covariance parameters (`test1@theta`, i.e., one per random effect) + 1 if there is a scaling parameter (which is always the case for `lmer` models according to `help("lmList", "lme4")`).

The AIC is calculated as $-2 \cdot L + k \cdot edf$ where $L$ is the log-likelihood and usually $k = 2$. As you see, the estimated degrees of freedom are used for a penalty term for the number of paramaters in a model. This term counters the effect that more complex models can always fit the data better than simpler models (at least if the models are nested). So, the whole point of AIC is that it allows comparing models with different number of parameters. Otherwise, you could just compare likelihoods directly.